# Python insert values from sensors in Mysql

Tags: python, mysql

struguling with this python script here. I'm trying to take a single reading out of dht22 and bh1750 and insert the values into MySQL but without success so far. When I run it the code does nothing untill interrupt by cnt+c.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os, MySQLdb, Adafruit_DHT, datetime, time, board, adafruit_bh1750

DHT_sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT22
DHT_pin = 4

i2c = board.I2C()

db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',user='admin', passwd='pass', db='weather)

humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(DHT_sensor, DHT_pin)
lux = adafruit_bh1750.BH1750(i2c)
dt = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

while True:
    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(DHT_sensor, DHT_pin)

if humidity is not None and humidity >= 0.0 and humidity <= 100.0 and temperature is not None and temperature > -100.0 and temperature < 150.0:
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO weather(temperature, humidity, lux, date) VALUES (" + str(temperature) + "," + str(humidity) + "," + str(lux) + ",'" + dt + "')")
    db.commit()
    cur.close()
    del cur
    db.close()
```

Comment: You have an infinite `while True:` loop, so you never get to the `if` line.

Comment: That should probably be indented so it's inside the loop. And then it should break out of the loop after inserting.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, os, MySQLdb, Adafruit_DHT, datetime, time, board, adafruit_bh1750

DHT_sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT22
DHT_pin = 4

i2c = board.I2C()

db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',user='admin', passwd='pass', db='weather')

humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(DHT_sensor, DHT_pin)
lux = adafruit_bh1750.BH1750(i2c)
dt = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

while True:
    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(DHT_sensor, DHT_pin)

    if humidity is not None and humidity >= 0.0 and humidity <= 100.0 and temperature is not None and temperature > -100.0 and temperature < 150.0:
        cur = db.cursor()
        #cur.execute("INSERT INTO weather(temperature, humidity, lux, date) VALUES (" + str(temperature) + "," + str(humidity) + "," + str(lux) + ",'" + dt + "')")
        cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO person SET humidity = '{humidity}', temperature= '{temperature}',lux='{lux}',date='{date}';")
        db.commit()
        cur.close()
        del cur
        db.close()
```

And you can use f string to write the sql command.

Comment: Hi @e3n thank you for your response. The code above throws an error: MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '18:00:28)' at line 1")

Comment: Uncomment Your old sql query and try with it

Comment: Still the same ... 
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '18:09:12)' at line 1")

Comment: but this time did record it to the database

Comment: ```f"INSERT INTO person SET humidity = '{humidity}', temperature= '{temperature}',lux='{lux}',date='{date}';"``` Use this inside execute @Inna Ivanova

Comment: this worked too but throws an error again :D quite annoying MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, '')

Comment: As far as i could find error is because your server is not running

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228705/discussion-between-e3n-and-inna-ivanova).